# It's now 12 years since Everett made his startling claims about Pirahã. How have his claims held up?

Tags: linguistic-universals, universal-grammar, piraha

How are they viewed by the scholarly community now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61104/discussion-on-question-by-lipno-its-now-12-years-since-everett-made-his-startli).